# European country with the longest border in South America

Tags: knowledge, geography

I am a country in Europe, but my longest land border is with a country in South America. What am I?

Comment: I was quite amazed to learn this fact, so I am genuinely surprised about the minuses.

Comment: I think downvotes may come from trivia questions not really feeling like puzzles.

Comment: Not a downvoter but to echo isaacg, the thing with a trivia question is you either know the answer already (like I did, being a geography fan) or can google it quickly and have the answer in seconds. An interesting tidbit, yes - but not truly a puzzle by itself really... Maybe better as a small part of a larger puzzle somehow?

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips guys. Lesson learned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a puzzle

Comment: I voted to close this as I keep losing points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear to be

> France.

The longest land border for

> metropolitan France (i.e. the bit in Europe) is with Spain and is 646 km long.

That is beaten by the overseas territory of

> French Guiana, which has a land border with Brazil that is 649 km long.

And as an extra factoid, its borders with

> Belgium and Suriname are fourth equal, at 556 km each.